# Express a function as a sum of an even and odd function(s).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a function $ \frac{x+1}{x^2-3x+4} $ which I've decomposed into $ \frac{x}{x^2-3x+4} + \frac{1}{x^2-3x+4} $.

By using the definitions of even and odd functions, I know that x is an odd function, $ x^2-3x+4 $ is neither even nor odd, and 1 is a constant and constants are considered even. so my question is: is an odd function over a function neither even nor odd, still odd? Same question from an a constant (even?) function.

Thank you for your help!

Also not sure if it's relevant, but for $ x^2-3x+4 $ we obtain non-real roots, and it is also worth noting that $ \frac{x}{x^2-3x+4} $ is zero when $ x=0 $. though $ x^2-3x+4 $ is always greater than roughly $ ~1.6 $.

Comment: Where does this function come from?

Comment: For the record, constant functions are not *considered* even: they *are* even.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate. The linked question has an answer which shows how to find the unique decomposition of this form.